# as3 assign another class to an existing class varriable?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables

I want to apply a new class to the same var name.

My code:

```
public var One:Word; 
//later called
One = new Word();

// later changed
One = new redWord();
```

How do I change the var "One" from the class name "Word" to the new class name "redWord"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class wildcards if you want to be able to assign variables of multiple types to a var:

```
public var One:*;
```

Alternatively if both of your classes extend the same class you can use that as the base class for your var:

```
public class Words{
    ...
}

public class Poem extends Words{
    ...
}

public class Prose extends Words{
    ...
}
public var Soliloquy:Words;
```

Comment: Don't even get me started on `Interfaces`!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to accept it yesterday but it was answered before I had permissions to accept. It said. You can not accept this answer yet. I had to run and back now. Again, thanks so much for your speedy help.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, variable names use lower case and class names use upper case. I would recommend changing `One` to `one` and `redWord` to `RedWord`.

To be able to assign to `One` instances of both `Word` and `redWord`, it must be declared of a type that is compatible with both. A possibility would be `Object`, but that may be too generic. Check if there is a common superclass to `Word` and `redWord`, and make `One` of that type.

The more specific your type is, the more errors you will discover at compile time, and the less nasty surprises you will be likely to find at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. +1 from me for that helpful info.